# how do I change python.exe window dimensions

Tags: python, dimensions

I'm curious wether you can manually change the dimensions for the python.exe program, as shown in the image below:
[EXEcuted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elMST.png)

I can change the height of the program window by just dragging it up or down but, it ironically wont let me change the width which is startign to become annoying, does anyone know of a way to widen it

Comment: You'd resize it the same way you'd change the height. Except this time your cursor would be on the side and a horizontal arrow should appear. It works fine for me

Comment: but it doesnt, it can get smaller, but not wider

Comment: I really don't understand how you are having a problem to be honest. I can make my python.exe widen by simply dragging it in the direction I want it to widen to.

Comment: Are you starting the python interpreter directly or in a terminal ? If you want more liberty on the window, try using other terminals (cmd, cygwin, powershell, IDLE ...)